# Why use "strlen30()" instead of "strlen()"?

Tags: c, sqlite, strlen

I've read and wondered about the source code of sqlite

```
static int strlen30(const char *z){
  const char *z2 = z;
  while( *z2 ){ z2++; }
  return 0x3fffffff & (int)(z2 - z);
}
```

Why use `strlen30()` instead of `strlen()` (in string.h)??

Comment: Unfortunately, SQLite sources say only the obvious thing - "Compute a string length that is limited to what can be stored in
lower 30 bits of a 32-bit signed integer.".

Comment: Maybe other parts of sqlite can't cope with strings larger than 1073741823 bytes -- and assuming they're smaller is the solution (I don't buy this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [commit message](http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?c=2008-12-10%2019:26:22) that went in with this change states:

> [793aaebd8024896c] part of check-in [c872d55493] Never use strlen(). Use our own internal sqlite3Strlen30() which is guaranteed to never overflow an integer. Additional explicit casts to avoid nuisance warning messages. (CVS 6007) (user: drh branch: trunk)

Comment: The commit message is horrible. How could cropping with `&` help with overflowing an integer I wonder?

Comment: @jeff Thank you for your answer! I'd like to read source code once again with your answer in mind. If there are some mistakes in English, I'd like to apologize.

Comment: @hority absolutely zero problems with your English so no need to apologise!

Comment: @sharptooth: Because only unsigned integers have well defined overflow behaviour. It isn't well-defined for signed integers. Also, it is not defined whether the difference of two char-pointers has the same byte-size as an ordinary integer. The commit message is clear and concise, but indeed misses a pointer to a detailed feature request or similar.

Comment: @phresnel: Could you please explain this in form of a detailed answer? It's really interesting and something I don't get.

Comment: @sharptooth: I've tried to give an answer in [your new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842880/why-reimplement-strlen-as-loopsubtraction/6843474#6843474) :)

Answer (score 2):

*(this is my answer from [Why reimplement strlen as loop+subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842880/why-reimplement-strlen-as-loopsubtraction/6843474#6843474) , but it was closed)*

---

I can't tell you the reason why they had to re-implement it, and why they chose `int` instead if `size_t` as the return type. But about the function:

```
/*
 ** Compute a string length that is limited to what can be stored in
 ** lower 30 bits of a 32-bit signed integer.
 */
static int strlen30(const char *z){
    const char *z2 = z;
    while( *z2 ){ z2++; }
    return 0x3fffffff & (int)(z2 - z);
}
```

## Standard References

The standard says in (ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)) *3.9.1 Fundamental Types*, 4.:

> Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer. 41)
>
> ...
>
> <sup>41)</sup>: This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type

That part of the standard does not define overflow-behaviour for signed integers. If we look at *5. Expressions*, 5.:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined, unless such an expression is a constant expression
>   (5.19), in which case the program is ill-formed. [Note: most existing implementations of C + + ignore integer
>   overflows. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating point
>   exceptions vary among machines, and is usually adjustable by a library function. ]

So far for overflow.

As for subtracting two pointers to array elements, *5.7 Additive operators*, 6.:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as ptrdiff_t in the *cstddef* header (18.1). [...]

Looking at *18.1*:

> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header *stddef.h*

So let's look at the C standard (I only have a copy of C99, though), *7.17 Common Definitions* :

> 4. The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer conversion rank
>      greater than that of signed long int unless the implementation supports objects
>      large enough to make this necessary.

No further guarantee made about `ptrdiff_t`. Then, Annex E (still in ISO/IEC 9899:TC2) gives the *minimum magnitude* for signed long int, but not a maximum:

```
#define LONG_MAX +2147483647
```

Now what are the maxima for `int`, the return type for `sqlite - strlen30()`? Let's skip the C++ quotation that forwards us to the C-standard once again, and we'll see in C99, Annex E, the minimum maximum for `int`:

```
#define INT_MAX +32767
```

## Summary

1. Usually, `ptrdiff_t` is not bigger than `signed long`, which is not smaller than 32bits.
2. `int` is just defined to be at least 16bits long.
3. Therefore, subtracting two pointers may give a result that does not fit into the  `int` of your platform.
4. We remember from above that for signed types, a result that does not fit yields undefined behaviour.
5. `strlen30` does applies a bitwise or upon the pointer-subtract-result:

---

```
          | 32 bit                         |
ptr_diff  |10111101111110011110111110011111| // could be even larger
&         |00111111111111111111111111111111| // == 3FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>
          ----------------------------------
=         |00111101111110011110111110011111| // truncated
```

---

That prevents undefiend behaviour by truncation of the pointer-subtraction result to a maximum value of 3FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub> = 1073741823<sub>10</sub>.

I am not sure about why they chose exactly that value, because on most machines, only the [most significant bit tells the signedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#One.27s_complement). It could have made sense versus the standard to choose the minimum `INT_MAX`, but 1073741823 is indeed slightly strange without knowing more details (though it of course perfectly does what the comment above their function says: truncate to 30bits and prevent overflow).

Comment: Thank you for your so detailly answer! I'm glad for your answer of my trivial question.I thought that "overflow" may be eternal problem for programing language...

Comment: I would guess they chose that upper bound to allow certain type of integer math to be performed with the results without incurring the Wrath of UB, but I would regard their logic as somewhat faulty, in that it would be legitimate for a 64-bit machine where individual objects were limited to less than 4 gigs to define `size_t` as `uint32_t` and`ptrdiff_t` as `int32_t`, and do anything it likes when subtracting the pointer near the end of a 3-gig object from one to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The CVS commit message says:

> Never use strlen(). Use our own internal sqlite3Strlen30() which is guaranteed to never overflow an integer. Additional explicit casts to avoid nuisance warning messages. (CVS 6007)

I couldn't find any further reference to this commit or explanation how they got an overflow in that place. I believe that it was an error reported by some static code analysis tool.

Comment: The reason is simple - `size_t` doesn't fit into `int` on 32-bit systems. So they crop most significant bits. I can't see how this help with overflow - cropping is cropping whether you call it that or not.

Comment: 2 billion symbols is enough actually, no need for terabytes.

Comment: @Rafał Thank you for your answer! I learned that I have to read the CVS commit message ,before I post the question... thx!(^o^)/